# Add a Proxy to your computer via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

How would I add and activate a proxy for my computer via terminal (without going into System Preferences.) Can I do that with `scutil --proxy` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [networksetup](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html).

See [man networksetup](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) for a full list.

Run this command via terminal.app

Example: setting http proxies.

```
sudo networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi proxy.yourdomain 9090

sudo networksetup -setproxybypassdomains Wi-Fi website1, website2, website3
```

Replace Wi-Fi with the approiate service name (wifi, ethernet, ..).

Comment: So this would look like: `networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi skyzip.com 9090` and `networksetup -setproxybypassdomains Wi-Fi https://www.youtube.com https://www.google.com`

Comment: If 9090 is the port your using than yes.  Also your sites are https, which needs to be enabled under -setsecurewebproxy.

Comment: So i'd just do `networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Wi-Fi skyzip.com 9090` instead?

Comment: Depends on your needs really.  If you want to proxy both http and https than you would enable both of them.  If you just want to send https to a proxy than just enable -setsecurewebproxy and set your bypass domains.